# Missing list of Algorithm in the content

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e, algorithmic

The command in my tex \listofalgorithms is detected as unrecognized command. In the generated pdf file. The page of Algorithm is presented, while in the content, this page is skipped. So what can I do to make the list of algorithme appear in the content list. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There are various different packages for typesetting algorithms, and the `\listofalgorithms` command is not used for all of them, or only when additional packages are used. So to be able to find out what the problem is in your case you should make a small example that reflects your situation, with the packages that you currently use and one example algorithm in it. Without this it will be hard to guess the solution to your problem.